# Join Table to Another Table then to Itself

Tags: sql, oracle, join, powerbuilder

I'm using PowerBuilder 12.5 Connected to Oracle 9. I want to select join my employee table to an employee_position table by emp_nbr, then use that emp_nbr to join into the employee table again.

However, *I do not want to use the employee_copy table* as I did below, since it will be taken down soon. Here's an image that illustrates what I want to do. :

[image]

I'm not sure if I should use nested selects or if this is possible only with inner joins. So this SQL code works, and I successfully retrieve the supervisor's name:

```
 SELECT "EMPLOYEE"."EMP_NBR",   
         "EMPLOYEE"."DEPT_NBR",   
         "EMPLOYEE"."SHOP",   
         "EMPLOYEE"."LAST_NAME",   
         "EMPLOYEE"."FIRST_NAME",   
         "EMPLOYEE"."MIDDLE_INITIAL",   
         "EMPLOYEE"."EMP_CLASS",   
         "EMPLOYEE_POSITION"."EMP_SUPERVISOR_ID",   
         "EMPLOYEE_COPY"."LAST_NAME",   
         "EMPLOYEE_COPY"."FIRST_NAME",   
         "EMPLOYEE_COPY"."MIDDLE_INITIAL"  
    FROM "EMPLOYEE",   
         "EMPLOYEE_POSITION",   
         "EMPLOYEE_COPY"  
   WHERE ( "EMPLOYEE"."EMP_NBR" = "EMPLOYEE_POSITION"."EMP_NBR" ) and  
         ( "EMPLOYEE_POSITION"."EMP_SUPERVISOR_ID" = "EMPLOYEE_COPY"."EMP_NBR" )
```

So my question is: How can I do this without using the employee_copy table? Also, this has to be done in one SQL query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No problem: A self-join will work fine:

```
 SELECT "EMPLOYEE"."EMP_NBR",   
     "EMPLOYEE"."DEPT_NBR",   
     "EMPLOYEE"."SHOP",   
     "EMPLOYEE"."LAST_NAME",   
     "EMPLOYEE"."FIRST_NAME",   
     "EMPLOYEE"."MIDDLE_INITIAL",   
     "EMPLOYEE"."EMP_CLASS",   
     "EMPLOYEE_POSITION"."EMP_SUPERVISOR_ID",   
     "EMPLOYEE_MGR"."LAST_NAME" as mgr_last_name,   
     "EMPLOYEE_MGR"."FIRST_NAME" as mgr_first_name,   
     "EMPLOYEE_MGR"."MIDDLE_INITIAL" as mgr_last_name  
FROM "EMPLOYEE",   
     "EMPLOYEE_POSITION",   
     "EMPLOYEE" EMPLOYEE_MGR  
WHERE ( "EMPLOYEE"."EMP_NBR" = "EMPLOYEE_POSITION"."EMP_NBR" ) and  
     ( "EMPLOYEE_POSITION"."EMP_SUPERVISOR_ID" = "EMPLOYEE_MGR"."EMP_NBR" )
```

Just use an alias for the EMPLOYEE table of EMPLOYEE_MGR.

Comment: Not familiar with powerbuilder but if it won't let you specify an alias, have the dba create a synonym of employee named employee_mgr.

Comment: Thanks Mark, I'll give this a shot tomorrow morning.

Comment: Fantastic! It works. You have a syntax error on `"EMPLOYEE_MGR"."FIRST_NAME as mgr_first_name", ` though. I never knew this syntax existed.

Comment: You can use pretty much any ANSI SQL syntax in PowerBuilder for a datawindow while in 'Syntax' mode of the Datawindow painter.

Comment: You have two choices...  1.) Use syntax mode in the datawindow painter and than you can alias the table just fine as the PB expert Matt suggested. 2.) Use graphic mode, do your first join, than right click, select table, select your employee table again and PB will put a second copy of the EMPLOYEE table. PB will put it's own alias but if you want to stay in graphical mode (there are advantages, like better multiple DB support) you can do it no problem.